# relative path jasperReport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a .jrxml JasperReport report. Within the I refer to children who are in the same folder.
If I put the route as it is down works in development, but to generate the war path is not valid.

```
<subreportExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport("./src/main/resources/report/General.jrxml")]]></subreportExpression>
```

I tried it with:

```
"General.jrxml"
"./Genereal.jrxml"
```

But in all cases it tells me:

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: General.jrxml (No such file or directory)
```

What is the correct syntax to access its jrxml on the child, you still are in the same folder.
Thank you very much.

Comment: ($P{"General.jrxml"}) ,  ($PGeneral.jrxml), ($P+"General.jrxml"), ($P+"/General.jrxml") = I've tried all these options, and not get it to work. No I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In the java class

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
parameters.put("path", classLoader.getResource("report/").getPath());
```

In the file jrxml

```
($P{path}+"General.jrxml")
```